# How to measure Capacitance of Insulation materials, taking into account the frequency and temperature

Tags: electromagnetism, measurement, capacitance

I have several insulation materials (plates, films and alike). I want to measure the complex permitivitty of these materials (Capacitance and tan delta).

The problem/question is: I did not find any works with these type of material at frequencies of 60Hz up to 10MHz, just 100MHz or more.

I have some documents that shows what is needed to do (generics), but the process is too much sensitive and I really would to know about similar works.

I do not know how to specify an equipment to measure this. Anyone have knowledge in this topic or know about published works that can help with this?

Comment: Generally, these measures are made with a general RLC bridge ... Don't remember what was the name of the bridge ... for those specific measuring parameters. This will help 
http://res-nlp.univ-lemans.fr/NLP_C_M14_G02/co/Contenu_91.html

Comment: In english, will help too https://www.tutorialspoint.com/electronic_measuring_instruments/electronic_measuring_instruments_other_ac_bridges.htm   ... you will need certainly a "setup board", and some "precision" components. A Q-meter could also help ... but it is now an "old thing" ...

Comment: @Antonio51 Thank you for the infos!! I will search about these types of measurement.

Comment: And here a link to Q-meter https://electricalvoice.com/q-meter-working-applications/   and a good general HP application http://kripton2035.free.fr/Resources/Impedance%20Measurement%20Basic.pdf